# Commit changes to a table once user has finished while storing temporary version (Oracle, Hibernate)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, transactions, temp-tables, hibernate-envers

What is a good approach for the design of the following problem with Oracle and Hibernate/JPA given the following constraints:

- user starts making changes to a table - create, update, delete
- changes are stored temporarily without saving over original data (only one set of changes exists for one user)
- the table is locked for edits but original data can be read for other users
- user eventually commits the changes and "unlocks" table

What I considered:

- Envers, although I only need a single version
- temporary tables in Oracle
- adding an additional column for each existing column (either in same or new table) and saving only changes - this needs manual work and having an operation (create, update, delete)
- any other alternatives?

Thank you for your design suggestions in advance.

Comment: What you are describing is Oracle's *default behavior*. Changes to data are only visible to the user making the changes until a `commit` is issued, which applies the changes permanently and makes them visible to other users. Tables can be explicitly locked for update so that only one user at a time can be making changes.

Comment: @pmdba great, can I do this over multiple sessions of the same user and only commit after the user has explicitly finished (committed)? I guess I have to somehow restore that session then.

Comment: Transactions are specific to a session. Each session will need to commit or rollback its changes independently. Ending a session (they cannot be "restored") will generally force a commit or rollback by default based on the tool in use and/or session parameters.